# how can i remove stored image along with app while removing from simulator

Tags: blackberry

I am getting an image and some information from a web server.

The image is stored in the path `file:///store/home/user/` and the information is stored in a hash table.

Whenever I delete the app, the information regarding my app and the image should also be deleted.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the solution for this question: [How to delete application data on install and reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879406/how-to-delete-application-data-on-install-and-reinstall)